# What could cause this roofing membrane tear, and how could it be mended?

Tags: roof

Poking around in the loft yesterday I found this tear in the fabric membrane under the tiles.  There is no corresponding tile damage visible from poking a camera around inside, nor sign of anything like rodent damage inside (though it's an odd place for a rodent anyhow).  What could cause such a tear?  I'd suspect wind damage at a rafter, rather than in the middle of a ripstop fabric.  More importantly, how can it be patched: can a section of membrane just be glued on the inside?

[image: Inside roof with damaged membrane]

If it's relevant this house is in the UK.

**Adendum** this seems to be the cause of water damage underneath which began last winter.  No work has been done on the roof in at least the last two years.  But I suppose damage from work earlier could take a while to manifest.

Comment: possible causes for a tear like that would be something like pressure (like stepping, kneeling, etc)...unlikely if there is tile above or putting up the membrane already torn...maybe expecting the tile to be good enough and owner not to notice?

Comment: @depperm really shoddy practice if it's the latter...  I suppose perhaps stepping *before* the tile was installed might explain it.

Comment: It might be an odd place for a rodent, but rodents _like_ odd places. Any signs of them elsewhere? Any droppings near here? TBH, it does look torn and not chewed, though.

Comment: @FreeMan no, none: I did look.

Comment: Yes... it looks like it might have been installed that way. The fabric looks kind of "loose" and probably the rows should overlap... was it installed by professionals? It's unlikely a rodent would have worked it's way into that attic and chewed a hole in that specific, random place for no apparent reason. Also it could have been torn from the inside, but it's likely the homeowner would be aware of that happening.

Comment: @gnicko it's not quite as loose as it looks: there was a considerable wind blowing and it's billowing in the wind.  If the rows should overlap this is a really shoddy design.  Any ideas for patching it?  Property is rental and I've no idea who did the installation; before I was here.

Comment: Perhaps it's a regional thing.... but it seems to me that one of the purposes of the fabric is to enhance the waterproof qualities of the roof...so I would imagine that the courses of fabric would overlap so that any water that got through the roofing would run down from one course to the next without falling through. Which means your leak could be anywhere up the roof, not necessarily at the hole in the membrane. You could probably glue on a patch and be somewhat better off than you are now, but it wouldn't necessarily solve the leak problem.